# HighCharts Context Button

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

Is there any way to programmatically change a context button's text? I've found that you can call the button's `textContent` within the actually element like so:

`$("#chart").highcharts().exportSVGElements[8].element.children[2].textContent = "Hello World"`

However, this doesn't resize the button and kind of just seems like a work-around to something that may otherwise be readily available another way I see not documentation for.

Does anyone know if this can be done?

Answer (score 1):

It can be changed easily during plugin initialization, like this:

```
$("#container").highcharts({
   . 
   . 
   . 
   exporting : {
       buttons: { 
           contextButton: { 
               text: "Some text"
           }
       }
   }
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/96sb2/

### Update

Dynamic change is possible but you will not like this solution. Only way to dynamically change some Highcharts data is to destroy chart and redraw it again.

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/96sb2/2/

Comment: Yes, I understand that but, is there a way I can change it outside of the plugin initialization?

Comment: Nope it is not possible, becuase it is rendered in SVG, so it is not dyncamically updated, when you modify text.